# Passing data from buttons to server through the modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On my site I have a modal window (Bootstrap) that can be shown by clicking a few buttons with such markup:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-link="Button 1">Click me!</a>
...
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-link="Button 2">Click me!</a>
...
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-link="Button 3">Click me!</a>
```

My modal window has this peace of code:

```
<form data-formname="Hero Section" class="forms">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="phone">Ваш телефон</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control phone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number:">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Send</button>
</form>
```

And JS:

```
$(".forms").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        phone: $(this).find(".phone").val(),
        formname: $(this).data('formname'),
        // datalink: ???
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: data
    });
    return false;
});
```

In addition to `phone` and `formname`, I want to get a button's `data-link`. Obviously, I can't use event.relatedTarget inside `$(".forms").on('submit', function(e) {...});`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use get the source in the `show.bs.modal` event handler

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var source = $(e.relatedTarget);
    //Persist it for later use      
    $(this).data('relatedTarget', source)
});
```

Now, You can use it to retrieve `source` element in the `form` submit event handler and get the `data-link`

```
$(".forms").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var source = $('#myModal').data('relatedTarget');
    var datalink = $(source).data('link');
});
```

Side note: *Identifiers in HTML must be unique*, remove duplicate *id="btn"*

Comment: You are the best!